# ionic $ An uncaught exception occured and has been reported to Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bower

first my project is work fine..... After restart System it show me the error(ionic $ An uncaught exception occured and has been reported to Ionic)

Gulp startup tasks: [ 'sass', 'watch' ]
Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729
Watching : [ 'www/**/*', '!www/lib/***/' ]
Running dev server: http://localhost:8100
Ionic server commands, enter:
  restart or r to restart the client app from the root
  goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
  consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
  serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
  quit or q to shutdown the server and exit

ionic $ An uncaught exception occured and has been reported to Ionic

spawn cmd ENOENT (CLI v1.4.5)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.4.5
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.0.22
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v0.12.7

reinstall npm-ionic,bower,cordova but still problem not solved.
please help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Last resort. Restart your pc.
2. This error is basically from
       ionic-cli, possible solutions kill all the npm server's running on
       your local machine.
3. Remove the latest cli version and install an
           older version of ionic-cli.